# none type has no attribute columns while converting to numeric

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Wrote a function to convert columns in specified lists to numeric:

```
    def conv_to_numeric(df,var_list):
      for col in var_list:
        if col not in df.columns:
          continue
        df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col],errors = 'coerce')
      return df
list=['A','B','E']
```

Func Call:-

```
dft=conv_to_numeric(dft,list)
```

Sample `dft` which columns are in object data type :-

```
Error:-None Type has no attribute columns
```

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3,71,31,839.24 | 5,31,49,395.23 | 0.0568 | 0.0261 | 0 |

Comment: I think the error is self-explanatory, `dft` is not a dataframe, but `None`

Comment: Yes so after I call this function it becomes None.I am not able to find the cause

Comment: The list variables are converted to `nan` for some reason

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Provided a sample of the `dft` which is in object dtype

Comment: please provide it as text, or better, dataframe constructor

Comment: ive added the markdown `df`